# Working with fragment above Main Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im working with fragments on my main activity I have a Edit Text and buttons in my main activity But when I opens fragment page and click exact at the spot of Edit Text the keyboard activates.

So it means the below activity is also in working at same time

Comment: So i want when i open fragment the Activity should not be there. Should i use a fragment instead of Main Activity or is there any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are designed to be inside an activity, if you don't want to make your activity visible you can use a full screen layout for fragment, to remove the clicks you can replace .add command with .replace when transacting to fragments give a background color to the root view of fragment layout also. I think this would help

```
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.ll_job_view_fragment_container, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(TAG_FRAGMENT_YOUR_VIEW)
                    .commit();
```

**Edit**
The replace may not help, If you inflate different fragments in the same container you just give the attribute `android:clickable="true"` to the top most parent view of each fragment that will help.

Comment: is there any way i use fragment and avoid main activity actions?
or i have to open a fragment on appcreate to replace main activity contents

Comment: Fragments doesn't have existence without activities. But you can load a full screen fragment if you don't want to display any content from Activity's layout. You can do the fragment transaction at the OnCreate method of main Activity

Comment: And the actions and buttons of mainactivity will be there even if you create a new fragment, because the purpose of activities and fragments are like that, for example if you want to load a side pane in activity without disturbing the buttons in activity you can create a fragment only for the side pane having a smaller layout than the activity. You can disable the touch going to activity if you give full size for the fragment container and give a background color like "white" to the layout of fragment.